# Understanding the Dosha calculation

Tags: ayurveda

I undertook 'Dosha' quiz here on this [site](https://yogainternational.com/article/view/dosha-quiz), the results of which were are follows:

Your Dosha Is: **Kapha**

**Kapha: 6 Vata: 3 Pitta: 5**

What exactly does this result mean in Ayurveda terminology? I mean how to analyze the result? I would like to understand what is Kapha/Vata/Pitta dosha?